# ACIIDOC to PDF in Python without need for files

Tags: python, pdf, asciidoc

So I am generating reports with Python and Ninja in the ASCIIDoc format.
But from within my app I need to convert them into PDF and upload them to another system.
I have seen that there are multiple HowTo for command line that involve ASCIIDoctor or other tools, but they always are invoked at OS level by starting a program or running a docker container and writing the output to a file.

Isn't there a way to perform those action within my app and get the PDF as a string that I can use for the upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the available tools to generate a PDF, which you could then read into memory as an opaque string that could be uploaded as needed.

If your question is: how do I generate and upload a PDF without installing any other tools?

Then the answer is that you'd have to implement the PDF generation logic yourself, rather than using tested tooling.